# To hit same request with different header each time in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, http-headers

How to hit same request 5 times with different headers each time in Jmeter API performance testing

Answer (score 0):

1. To run request 5 times put it under the [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) and set "Loop Count" to 5
2. The headers can be added/modified using [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager)
3. Header values can be parameterized using [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

Demo:

[image]

The most frequently used parameterization approach is storing the test data in the .csv file and using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)